# What does php's echo do?

Tags: php, html, server-side

I am a beginner at php and I am wondering what echo does. It seems to do very different things under different circumstances. This demonstrates what I mean.
index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <?php
        echo "echoed by php";
    ?>
    <button onclick="buttonClick()">Get stuff from server</button>
    <p id="output"></p>
    <script>
        function buttonClick()
        {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "backend.php", true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

backend.php:

```
<?php
    echo "stuff from server";
?>
```

The first echo (the one in index.php) acts similarly to document.write in js: it displays something. The echo in backend.php, however, seems to be the responseText.
What exactly is going on? Does the echo in backend.php get compiled into plain text? If so, does that automatically become the response text?

Comment: They all are "plain text": `echo` just prints back whatever you asked, it does not carry any additional semantics.

Comment: You're going to need to think about the different layers at work in your application.

Comment: A great place to find these kind of things out is from the PHP manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Comment: Echo sends output to the output buffer,  If it's embedded in HTML (which is also being sent to the output buffer) then it appears that it writes that to the "source".  Which it basically does, but only because the source is also being output.  So in the second example the only output is that of echo, in the first its the combination of the HTML and PHP as it executes.

Answer (score 1):

Echo simply outputs the strings that it is given, if viewing in the browser it will output the strings to the browser, if it's through command line then it will output the strings to the command line.

In index.php and backend.php echo is doing the same thing in both, the difference is you're sending a GET request to get the contents of backend.php, however you're viewing the index.php echo directly in the browser.

If you directly view backend.php in your browser you will see the echo in the same way as index.php.

Of course more commonly you would return a JSON response of some data in backend.php using json/_encode to be displayed using JS in the index.

I hope this has helped

Edit: to answer you directly, there is no compiling going on, echo is simply printing out the string. However yes, the echo string is the response

Answer (score 0):

Echo simply sends strings to the output buffer.  There are many other "things" that do this such as `print`, `printf` and `var_export`, `var_dump`, `print_r` for arrays, etc.  Each with their own "traits".

Whats confusing you between the two is your neglecting the fact that HTML in a PHP file is output as that file is read.  So with the `echo` inline to that as it outputs the HTML it hits a bit of PHP code and the server executes that resulting in a bit of output there, then it continues to output the HTML.  So at the end you get your HTML + PHP output as the source.

In the second example the only output is from echo in PHP.  But both go to the output buffer, which is eventually sent as the body of the response back to the client.

Hope that makes sense.